# Calculations of bat speed and pace of a delivery

Tags: cricket

I have two questions:

1. How is the bat speed of batsmen calculated?

   (I believe it is from change in position of bat in each frame divided by time)
2. Does the nature of the pitch affect the pace of a bowler?
   (I know that ball behaves differently on different pitches after hitting the deck)

   Generally the pace is calculated as distance taken by the ball till pitching or hitting the bat divided by the time taken; as the speed is calculated before the ball pitches the ground, Will the nature of the pitch/ground/soil play any significant role in the pace of a delivery?

Answer (score 2):

Bat speed in cricket is the velocity that a batter can achieve with his customized slab of English willow, But i believe there is no standard of how to measure it has been accepted. 
It is largely the television channels that measure the speed of bat and it is from the video their cameras capture. Its mostly the speed of swing from stationary position to hitting the ball position.

The nature of pitch surely affects the pace of ball. A dry dusty pitch and a very damp pitch is slower because the ball grips and holds to the surface more. A skiddy kind of pitch with a little moisture will have a slight increase in pace due lower value of coefficient of friction. The difference in pace caused by difference in the texture of the pitch is less than 5mph.

Comment: Bat speed calculation is ok. But while calculating the speed of a delivery , it is calculated even before the ball hits the ground. so virtually the type of the pitch doesn't matter in calculating the speed, the nature of the pitch does matter to the batsmen alone , coz the d pace at which the ball reaches the batsmen will vary. in hard pitches like Perth the ball(with speed 140kmph) reaches the batsmen with good pace,while in sub continental pitches the same 140ks delivery looses speed after hitting the deck, arrives to the batsmen with much lesser speed.

Comment: Are you sure about this?

Comment: From knowledge of bowling on diff conditions , i think the grip the bowler gets during run up and during the release point(at the landing crease) varies from one pitch to other. if the pitch is damp , eventually the landing crease will also be damn and it will affect the bowlers release. we bowlers need the landing spot to be hard and griper to get more speed

Comment: umesh yadav generally clocks 140-148 in Indian pitches where as in Australia he clocked 146-151 consistently.

Comment: I am not talking about any other factor. Only about Pitch. Speed is calculated from point of release so foot landing need not be considered in this case. And the example you showed itself shows a variation in pace.

Comment: i say that landing crease will also have the same texture as that of the entire pitch.

Comment: it dosent affect the ball speed calculation. U aint getting the point huh? If you consider the grip then you can consider the wind speed, wind angle, time of the day, newness of the ball. etc

Comment: http://www.answerbag.com/q_view/2523 , tells how radar gun is used..

Comment: yeah.. i accept all the physical conditions do play a part. For pace bowler run up and release are his assets.

Comment: Those are the factors of generating pace. Not calculating the Speed of the ball. Hope i have made it clear for you.

Comment: what u said is correct, no doubt in tht. i'm saying that the all other factors affects speed of delivery.

Comment: @Rohit The speed of the ball shown on TV is the fastest speed at any given point of time. This, invariably is just when the ball is released from the bowler's hand. Once the ball pitches, irrespective of the pitch conditions, there is a drastic fall in the speed, which has to be countered differently on each surface by the batsman. 

To answer your question, the speed captured by the speed gun and shown on your television set is the speed before the ball hits the surface.

Answer (score 1):

The speed of a bowler is calculated while releasing the ball itself. 
**So the nature of pitch doesnt affect the speed of a bowler. As SIMPLE as that**

Comment: yeah I agree. I have seen on t.v.- the speed of the ball is the speed when released from bowlers hand. then it  decreases before hitting the ground. After pitching the speed decreases drastically.

Comment: A good answer here should include math and technique, not sure why this was accepted, but this is not a good answer to this question.